# Setting session based NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS in Oracle Reports

Tags: oracle, oraclereports, reportserver

I'm trying to create a report that can switch between English and (Canadian) French number formatting (1,234.56 vs 1 234,56) but am having some troubles.

Before I get into what I have tried I'd like to say that in the past we have always converted the French number to a character, and than made the appropriate string modifications there, but this obviously isn't the best solution and I'm trying to find something better going forward.

The first thing I tried doing was adding the following line to the BEFORE REPORT trigger in the Oracle Report itself:

```
srw.do_sql ('alter session set nls_numeric_characters = '', ''');
```

I have my number fields set up with the format mask "(NNNGNNNGNN0D00)" so I would assume the G's and D would use the session's NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS setting but they don't seem to.

To see if the setting was actually changing I created the following query in the report and displayed it's output:

```
select value from nls_session_parameters
where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS';
```

Sure enough the output changed from '.,' to ', ' using my alter session command.

After researching some more online I read that the change really needs to be made in the Oracle Report Server configuration as per this documentation - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/bi.1012/b14048/pbr_conf.htm#i1013352

I contacted the team responsible for our Oracle Application Server and had them try inserting the configurations we need to set up English and French number formatting and they added in the following:

```
<environment id="EN">
    <envVariable name="NLS_LANG" value="AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1"/>
 </environment>
 <environment id="FR">
    <envVariable name="NLS_LANG" value="FRENCH_CANADA.WE8ISO8859P1"/>
    <envVabiable name="NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS" value="', '"/>
 </environment>
```

The report server was restarted and I entered in the URL to request the report, along with the ENVID=FR parameter, but still no luck. The report runs but the number formatting is still using the ,'s and .'s for grouping and decimal separation.

Does anyone know what we're missing or what else we could try?

Comment: You can specify the characters with the [optional third parameter to `to_char()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions201.htm); not sure if it's possible or practical to do that in your report query though...

Comment: Yes, in the past we've always converted to characters in order to display it correctly, but I'm looking for a way to do it while keeping it as a number field. The reasons for this are 1) It will mean less changes when converting a English reports to French in the future. 2) If the report has summary fields to show totals we then need to have queries which bring back both the number (for the summary to use) and the to_char'ed version (to display on the report) and it adds work for the developer. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and did to_char() where that NLS format needs to apply.